# How to mount vmware shared folders in WSL2

Tags: mount, vmware-fusion

I have a Mac, and install a Win10 VM by vmware fusion, the shared folders between Mac and Win10 VM use drive letter Z: or \vmware-host

And I mapped a network address \192.168.111.49\Builds to drive letter Y:

Then I install WSL2 in the Win10 VM, and linux subsystem Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I want to mount all drive letter in Ubuntu, C: is automatically mount /mnt/c

And i use these cmd to mount Y:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/y
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=xxx,password=xxxx,domain=xxx //192.168.111.49/Builds /mnt/y
```

It's OK

However, when I try mount Z:, it's not work

```
# from vmware official site
$ sudo vmhgfs-fuse -d .host:/ /mnt/z -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

# try to use drvfs
$ sudo mount -t drvfs Z: /mnt/z
mount: /mnt/z: special device Z: does not exist.
<3>init: (457) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:489: /bin/mount failed with status 0x2000
<3>init: (457) ERROR: MountPlan9:478: mount cache=mmap,rw,trans=fd,rfdno=3,wfdno=3,msize=65536,aname=drvfs;path=Z:;symlinkroot=/mnt/ failed 2
No such file or directory

# like network address
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=xxx,password=xxx //vmware-host/ /mnt/z
mount: /mnt/z: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.
```

And I check my open-vm-tools version

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade open-vm-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
open-vm-tools is already the newest version (2:11.1.5-1~ubuntu20.04.2).
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

It's already newest.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason is I run cmd or powershell as **administrator**

If I don't use administator, the following mount is OK

```
sudo mount -t drvfs Z: /mnt/z
```